# Is it possible to write one function for std::string and std::wstring?

Tags: c++, string, templates, stl, stdstring

I just wrote a simple utility function for std::string. Then I noticed that the function would look exactly the same if the `std::string` was a `std::wstring` or a `std::u32string`. Is it possible to use a template function here? I am not very familiar with templates, and `std::string` and `std::wstring` are templates themselves, which might be an issue.

```
template<class StdStringClass>
inline void removeOuterWhitespace(StdStringClass & strInOut)
{
  const unsigned int uiBegin = strInOut.find_first_not_of(" \t\n");

  if (uiBegin == StdStringClass::npos)
  {
    // the whole string is whitespace
    strInOut.clear();
    return;
  }

  const unsigned int uiEnd   = strInOut.find_last_not_of(" \t\n");
  strInOut = strInOut.substr(uiBegin, uiEnd - uiBegin + 1);
}
```

Is this a proper way to do it? Are there pitfalls with this idea. I am not talking about this function but the general concept of using a templated class `StdStringClass` and calling the usual `std::string` functions like find, replace, erase, etc.

Comment: I see nothing particulary wrong. For me, our template seems good. No problem for using some specific function. It just not compile if you give a parameter which haven't used function inside template

Comment: `find` and `replace` will require some trickery, since the character types are different. For example, the function above would not work for `std::wstring`, because `std::wstring::find_first_not_of` does not take a `const char*`, but a `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: Seem's fine for me either except instead of `unsigned int` i would recommend use `typename StdStringClass::size_type` or auto if c++11 is enabled.

Comment: @Benjamin Maybe the searched string `" \t\n"` should be wrapped to `StdStringClass(" \t\n")`, does it solves that?

Comment: @Radek: No, because that would try to call a constructor that doesn't exist for `wstring`.

Comment: the correct name for this function would be `trim` btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a good Idea, But I'd build the template on top of `std::basic_string` rather then general `StdStringclass`

```
template<class T>
inline void removeOuterWhitespace(std::basic_string<T>& strInOut)
{
  constexpr auto delim[] = {T(' '),T('\t'),T('\n'),T(0)};
  const auto uiBegin = strInOut.find_first_not_of(delim);

  if (uiBegin == std::basic_string<T>::npos)
  {
    // the whole string is whitespace
    strInOut.clear();
    return;
  }

  const auto  uiEnd   = strInOut.find_last_not_of(delim);
  strInOut = strInOut.substr(uiBegin, uiEnd - uiBegin + 1);
}
```

I would also ditch the MSDN-style "inout" notation in favro for simpler name like `str`. programmer will guess themselves that `str` *is* the result since it is passed as non-const reference and function returns `void`.

also, I changed `unsigned int` to `auto`. all the standard C++ containers/strings return `size_t` when returning indexes. `size_t` might not be `unsigned int`. `auto` matches itself to the right return value.

Comment: Is `T(0)` supposed to be `T(' ')`?

Comment: it's supposed to be the null terminator. looking again I forgot the whitespace, I'll add it

Comment: I see. Very good answer. Unfortunately, C++11 is not available to me. I hope to be able to circumvent `auto`. The gcc compiler complained when I use `size_t` some time ago, hence I switched to `unsigned int`.

Comment: you can still do it with C++03. the instead of `constexpr auto...` just write `const T` and `std::basic_string<T>::size_type` for the rest

Comment: I'd advise against using `basic_string` here explicitly, and for one very good reason: what if I later switch to some alternative string class that provides the interface I used here? I'd use a `typename StringType` and use `StringType::value_type` to get at its underlying character type. That being said, it might be better to use some form of `isspace` predicate instead of a hardcoded list of whitespace. Especially if things like `wstring` are used (implying more-than-only-ASCII whitespace characters).

Comment: @rubenvb: Thank you for your comment. Both are important points which I will consider.

Comment: If you are templating on `basic_string`, you might as well template all three (the character type, the traits and the allocator) rather than just one.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your template works as expected (haven't checked...sorry), another option would be to wrap the function in class, and control which types of strings classes you'd like the function to be applied to using constructors.

**EDIT**: added illustrative framework

**EDIT2** one that compiles (at least with vs2015) :-)

```
class StringType1;
class StringTypeN;

class str {

    //template function
    template<class StdStringClass>
    inline void removeOuterWhitespace(StdStringClass & strInOut)
    {
        //.
        //.
        //.
    }

public:
    //constructors
    str(StringType1 &s1) { removeOuterWhitespace(s1); }
    //.
    //.
    //.
    str(StringTypeN &sN) { removeOuterWhitespace(sN); }


};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT3** Proof of concept

```
#include <iostream>
class incr {
    //template function
    template<class incrementor>
    inline void removeOuterWhitespace(incrementor & n)
    {
        n++;
    }
public:
    //constructors
    incr(int &n1) { removeOuterWhitespace(n1); }
    incr(double &n1) { removeOuterWhitespace(n1); }
    incr(float &n1) { removeOuterWhitespace(n1); }
};

int main() {
    int n1 = 1;
    double n2 = 2;
    float n3 = 3;
    std::cout << n1 << "\t" << n2 << "\t" << n3 << std::endl;
    auto test1 = incr(n1);
    auto test2 = incr(n2);
    auto test3 = incr(n3);
    //all variables modified
    std::cout << "all variables modified by constructing incr" << std::endl;
    std::cout << n1 << "\t" << n2 << "\t" << n3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate further and add some code to illustrate your answer. Rght now it is not a helpful answer, as it does not provide a definitive solution to OP problem.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, I do not see how this would reduce the code duplication. In the class, I would still need to implement the above code for each type of string. My aim is to stick to the DRY principle. Using one template method seems much more elegant to me.

Comment: Fabian, @Revolver_Ocelot , I edited the answer and added illustrative code. Fabian, yes i know there is some extra code, but the benefit is that you gain control. cheers!

Comment: (1) This code will not compile (syntax errors, there is no actual function call in constructor)    
(2) How this is better than simply calling templated function?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot it is `not` **better** , it simply adds control, for whenever you might want to avoid runtime errors.

Comment: Fabian, @Revolver_Ocelot, added proof of concept. as i said, this method adds control, and your ide/compiler will complain if you try to pass values that you have not designed your template routine for. cheers!

Comment: It does not answer OP question about potential pitfalls and proper way of implementing a generic function. In fact it has numerous problems: (a) You need to manually specify all classes which can be used. Any class which does satisfy requirements for function, but not listed cannot be used.  (b) You can create a useless instance of this class, which cannot even be used as predicate. (c) It is more complex and less generic than checking for requrements and disabling function through SFINAE. Even without SFINAE it is easier to add control through function overloads which calls template.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot **a)** that's the whole point **b)** true, but that's easily fixed with a bit of imagination. in other words, it depend on implementation, **c)** not sure about that. Regardless, In the myriad of ways of doing things with c++, this is just another one, OP - or anybody else =  can add it to his arsenal if he wishes to, or can completely disregard it. cheers! :)